# calling an array of dictionaries initialised in a class

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, init

what am i doing wrong in swift?

```
 class ActivityDetailsModel {
    var ActivityProfile: [[String]]
    init(ActivityProfile: [[String]]){
        self.ActivityProfile = ActivityProfile
    }   
} 

var act = ActivityDetailsModel(ActivityProfile: ["cell2"+"firName": "two"])
```

gives Cannot invoke initializer for type 'ActivityDetailsModel' with argument of type (ActivityProfile: [String: String])

Answer (score 0):

The type signature of the variable `ActivityProfile` is an `Array` of `Array` rather than the expected `Array` of `Dictionary`.

This uses the alternative syntax to make it clear

```
class ActivityDetailsModel : Printable {
  var activityProfile : [[String:String]]

  init(activityProfile: [[String:String]]) {
    self.activityProfile = activityProfile
  }

  var description : String {
    return activityProfile.description
  }
}

var act = ActivityDetailsModel(activityProfile: [["cell2"+"firName": "two"]])
println(act)
```

PS: it's easier to read to start variable names with a lowercase letter

Comment: Could `[Dictionary<String,String>]` also be written as `[[String, String]]`? I'm fairly new to Swift syntax, just wanted to check.

Comment: almost : `[[String:String]]`

Comment: Thanks and the comment about vars and lowercase noted. 
I tried your code in Playground and got  an empty dictionary, with __lldb_expr_195.ActivityDe
I actually phrased my question all wrong apologies!
What I am trying to achieve is an array of dictionaries in my class.
I can get the straight forward dictionary to work but not an array of dictionaries!\

Comment: add the line `act.activityProfile` in the playground

Comment: you can also implement the `Printable` protocol to improve the display of the instance. I edited the post